# How to convert `LogTicks[0, 2][[1, 2]]` to a regular number

Tags: output-formatting, conversion, built-in-symbols

I want to convert the $10^i$ tick labels generated by `LogTicks` of the `CustomTicks` package to regular numbers. The first tick label is in element `[[1,2]]` of the object generated by `LogTicks`. `FullForm` tells me the format is as follows:

```
LogTicks[0, 2][[1, 2]] // FullForm
```

> ```
> \!\(
> TagBox[
> StyleBox[
> RowBox[{"DisplayForm", "[", 
> RowBox[{"SuperscriptBox", "[", 
> RowBox[{"10", ",", "0"}], "]"}], "]"}],
> ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
> ShowStringCharacters->True,
> NumberMarks->True],
> FullForm]\)
> ```

Actually, in the notebook it looks different:

[image]

Subsequently, I can use `ToExpression` to obtain the regular number 1:

```
ToExpression[%]
(* 1 *)
```

But it doesn't work in one step:

```
ToExpression[LogTicks[0, 2][[1, 2]]]
```

> ToExpression::notstrbox: 10^0 is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language input.

What would be the command to get

```
command[LogTicks[0, 2][[1, 2]]]
(* 1 *)
```

and what is the reason why my approach failed?

Comment: Does this work for you general use-case? `command[expr_] := First@Cases[expr, SuperscriptBox[x_, y_] :> x^y]`

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to return `expr` if it can't be converted that way (e.g., some elements of `LogTicks[0, 2][[All, 2]]` are just empty strings ""

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the structure of these objects, so I'm not sure how to generalize it. You could use and `If` statement to check the structure of `expr` first, and return `expr` if it's an empty string or something. Otherwise, why doesn't `ToExpression@FullForm@expr` work?

Comment: I somehow can't test the objects generated by `LogTicks` with `If`. That's what I tried first. Also, `ToExpression@FullForm@expr` does fail with "is not a string box" error. I really don't understand the structure of these objects, too, that's the main aspect of the question.

Comment: What about `ToExpression@ToBoxes@FullForm@expr`? Or maybe just `ToExpression@ToBoxes@expr`?

Comment: Yes, perfect, that works! Thanks! Do you understand why it does? Can you make it an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never sat down to understand the front-end parsing/display stuff. I just try things until they work when I run into these kinds of problems. Maybe someone else can come along and explain it for us and write and answer instead.